# IndexError: list index out of range for working code

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, generator

Consider the code given:

[image: PyCharm]

It shows list index out of range.

```
enter code here
```

for x in range(max_count):
        try:
            result = next(gen)
            assert len(result) == tuple_length, "invalid length"
            for element in result:
                assert x == element, "unexpected value"
        except StopIteration as si:
            pass

try:
        next(gen)
        assert False, "generator did not finish as expected"
    except StopIteration as se:
        pass

Comment: Source code is text; please paste the code here, with the full traceback of the exception.

Comment: def generator_zip(seq1, seq2, *more_seqs):

    for i in range(len(min(seq1,seq2,more_seqs)) - 1):
        l1 = []
        l2 = []
        for s1 in seq1,seq2:
            l1.append(s1[i])
        for s2 in more_seqs:
            l2.append(s2[i])
        l = l1 + l2
        p = tuple(l)
        yield list(p)

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add code. Once you pasted it in your question, select all the source code and click the `{}` button to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're order of operations is all messed up...
`range(len(min(seq1,seq2,more_seqs))`
doesn't return what you think it does.  Here, you're using `min` and finding the list which contains the smallest content, then taking the length of whatever list `min` returns.

Here's some sample code to prove the point:

```
seq1 = [100, 200, 300]
seq2 = [10, 20, 30, 40]
seq3 = [1000, 2000]

print len(min(seq1, seq2, seq3))
#prints 4 (the length of seq2 because it has the smallest values)

print min(len(x) for x in [seq1, seq2, seq3])
#prints 2 which is the minimum of all the lengths
```

Comment: Here Iam using variable args.The function definition is as follows:def generator_zip(seq1, seq2, *more_seqs):

Comment: What are you expecting the function to yield?  A huge tuple which is all the values in all the sequences?  Please clarify.

Comment: @catwalker333 Looks like the assignment is to basically re-implement zip as a generator. i.e izip from itertools.

Comment: if I pass range(5),"abc",range(2),"apple",it should return [(0,'a',0,'a'),(1,'b',1,'p').If if give range(1, 5), "abc", [1, 2] as input it should give [(1, 'a', 1), (2, 'b', 2)] as output.All this should be done using generators.